# Divide and conquer algorithm to find one element that isn't repeated

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

If I have a sorted list of integers where every element except one is repeated, how would I find the singleton element in less than O(n) time?

For example: (−2, −2, 5, 5, 5, 67, 67, 72, 80, 80, 80, 80) would return 72.

I'm fairly certain binary search is involved in this, but not sure how to implement it. I'm just looking for the pseudocode here.

I'm thinking to iterate through the list, and binary search for the last occurrence of the current element. If the index of that is the same as the one we're currently on, that's the singleton element. If not, keep going. That would be O(nlogn) I think.

Comment: Is the input always sorted?

Comment: Yes, always a sorted list.

Comment: And what makes you think it is actually possible?

Comment: I don't see why not considering binary search is O(logn) and I would (at the worst possible case) have to iterate through the entire list before I found the singleton element, which would make it o(nlogn). Am I missing something?

Comment: "I'm thinking to iterate through the list" - you can't do that in less than O(N) time

Comment: O(n) < O(n log n) but you seems to be asking less than O(n). O(n) is kind of easy actually. Binary search O(log n) does not look at neighbors

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes you're correct. Would it be possible to do it in O(n) exactly? From what I'm seeing, it's not, but perhaps iterating through the list isn't the answer.

Comment: If you run binary search, it only tells you if the number exists at all, not that there are repeats or not. At a minimum, you'd have to look at every number once

Comment: Right. I was thinking to use binary search to find the last occurrence of an element, so instead of iterating through the entire list, we could skip all the repeated incidences. But I guess worst case that's still O(nlogn). Thank you

Comment: @79t97g See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58261674/5218354) for two Python implementations, both O(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each integer can be repeated an arbitrary number of times, the best algorithm would be `O(n)` as there is no way to avoid iterating through every integer. Simply iterate through the list and keep a counter of how many of the same integer has been found in a row. If the counter is only one and a new integer is discovered, then terminate, as we have found the non-repeating integer.

If we know that all numbers are repeated the same number of times (except for the one which is not repeated), we can use binary search to achieve even better time complexity. However, based on your example problem, it looks like this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

An O(n) Python implementation:

```
def find_singletons(items):
    singletons = []
    a, b = items[:2]
    for item in items[2:]:
        if a != b and b != item:
            singletons.append(b)
        a, b = b, item
    return singletons


items = [-2, -2, 5, 5, 5, 67, 67, 72, 80, 80, 80, 80]
print(find_singletons(items))
# [72]
```

---

Another O(n) Python implementation (using a counter):

```
def find_singletons2(items):
    singletons = []
    count = 1
    last_item = items[0]
    for item in items[1:]:
        if last_item != item:
            if count == 1:
                singletons.append(last_item)
            count = 1
        else:
            count += 1
        last_item = item
    return singletons


items = [-2, -2, 5, 5, 5, 67, 67, 72, 80, 80, 80, 80]
print(find_singletons(items))
# [72]
```